# node-mongo-native findAndModify callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been trying to get code in callback executed for couple of days now but am I not sure what I am doing wrong. Following is the code which I am trying to execute. For some reason callback is not getting executed even though the sequence is getting incremented.

Please help.

```
var seqCollection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'seq');
seqCollection.findAndModify(
    {"_id": "name"}, [], {$inc: {"seq": 1}}, {},
    function (err, result) {
        if (err){
            console.log('--------- There is a an error ------------');
        } else{
            console.log('--------- New Value:' + JSON.stringify(result) + '------------');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not use new Collection

use

```
db.collection("seq").findAndModify(....)
```

also docs are here

http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify

Comment: Thank you. I had already checked the docs and applied your solution. Still no avail.

Comment: Just noticed - I am having callback issue with update statement too but callbacks are getting called for find, findOne and insert methods. I guess the issue is with methods requiring multiple params. I have updated driver.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find the problem .....

```
client.close();
```

was misplaced in the code.